# Why is the conformal factor/characteristic function of a conformal map differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products, conformal-geometry

Suppose $f$ is a conformal map between real inner product spaces. Then for all vectors $x, v, u$, $\langle d_xfv, d_x f u\rangle = \lambda(x)\langle v, u\rangle$ for some positive $\lambda(x)$.

I am currently reading the proof of Liouville's theorem on conformal maps between real inner product spaces due to Rolf Nevanlinna. The first step is to differentiate the inner product $\langle d_xfv, d_x f u\rangle$ for some vectors $v, u$. The proof uses the fact that $\lambda$ is differentiable wrt $x$. But I don't quite understand why this is the case. Fix some $v \ne 0$, then $\lambda(x)=|d_xfv|/|v|$ for all $x$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: when you say $f$ is conformal, could you be explicit about the definition (I ask because I've seen a few non-equivalent definitions in different contexts)

Comment: Sure. I assume the differential $d_xf$ is a nonzero multiple of some bijective linear isometry. Or for all $u, v$ in its domain, $\langle d_xfv, d_xfu\rangle = \lambda\langle v, u\rangle$ for some positive $\lambda$. So it is a function that preserves unoriented angles.

Comment: I mean are you assuming any further regularity on $f$? $C^1$ or $C^2$ or $C^{\infty}$ or analytic?

Comment: In that elementary proof $f$ is assumed to be $C^4$.

Comment: Ok, then in this case the differentiability of $\lambda$ is easy because if we fix a unit vector $v$, then $\lambda(x)=\langle df_x(v),df_x(v) \rangle$. Now, $f$ being $C^4$ implies that the mapping $x\mapsto df_x$ is $C^{k-1}$ (usually by definition) and thus $x\mapsto df_x(v)$ is also $C^{k-1}$, and thus $\lambda$ is also $C^{k-1}$. In your case $k=4$, so $\lambda$ is $C^3$.

Comment: @user580918 Thank you for the comment. I can't understand the last step, would you elaborate on why the differentiability of $x\mapsto d_xf$ suggests the differentiability of $x \mapsto d_xf(v)$?

Comment: Say $f:V\to W$ is a map between Banach spaces. Then, $df$ is a mapping $V\to L(V,W)$ (the space of bounded linear transformations), and let $\epsilon_v:L(V,W)\to W$ be the "evaluation at $v$" mapping $\epsilon_v(T)=T(v)$. Then, $x\mapsto df_x(v)$ is simply the composition $\epsilon_v\circ (df)$. This is a composition of a bounded linear (hence $C^{\infty}$) mapping and $C^{k-1}$ mapping, thus (by the chain rule) $\epsilon_v\circ df$ has the same regularity as $df$, namely $C^{k-1}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @user580918